# How can i monitor/listen whether Spring @Scheduled bean is running or not

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

We are using `@Scheduled` bean in our application to run a piece of code which needs to run every 30 minutes, but i want to monitor this scheduled bean whether it is running properly or not.
I want to generate an alert if for some reason the scheduled bean did not get invoked.
Does spring support any listener to monitor the `@Scheduled` bean. Kindly help.

Comment: Could you make the bean write to a log file when it runs? To test if it *hasn't* run would be more difficult, but you could have an external script that runs on its own schedule to check that the log file has been updated at the appropriate time.

Comment: why do you think scheduled bean method wont get invoked? If this scheduled bean does not get invoked then I dont think any alerting from within application will not work as well and probably your application down.   
One solution as suggested by @DaveyDaveDave . If you already have some standalone alerting systems you can add code in scheduled bean method to publish to alerting system that this run was successful by sending event or updating key. If for some reason it did not execute then your alert will be triggered in the monitoring system as there was no event from scheduled bean method.

Comment: Thanks..I will try the suggested solution

Answer (score 1):

One solution: [Spring Boot production monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131012/spring-boot-production-monitoring)

other solution: Each time scheduler completes the job just send a mail and check that.