# Spring Boot production monitoring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, monitoring, spring-boot-actuator

Spring Boot Actuator exposes a lot of metrics and information of the deployed container. However, production operations guys probably don't want to stare at pure JSON objects on their browser :)

What would be good "standard" tools for monitoring this in production? This would include graphs, triggers for alerts, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The spring-boot-admin project is also a great monitoring tool that your production support guys may be interested in.  It doesn't process and graph the metrics at all like graphite+grafana, but it is a great simple tool to setup and use to see the state of all of your running spring-boot applications.

https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin

Answer (score 3):

You're right! Looking at JSON Objects all day is not that pretty. One setup that our team finds handy is to use the following

- [jmxtrans](https://github.com/jmxtrans/jmxtrans/wiki) to export the data to [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/).
- [Graphana](http://grafana.org/) to show the data in a nice way, after pulling the metrics from Graphite. Documentation to do that is [on Graphana's website](http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/graphite/)
- [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/) for triggering alerts, pulling the same data from Graphite, there's a nice module [here](https://github.com/pyr/check-graphite) for that.